Springboot micrometer Opentelemetry
I am trying to enable opentelemetry in a Springboot service using the approach here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/3.3-SNAPSHOT/reference/actuator/tracing.html#actuator.micrometer-tracing.tracer-implementations.otel-otlp
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37278
I have imported the 3 dependencies outlined in the link above and made the management settings as mentioned on the issue. However, the traces are showing up only for the actuator health endpoint and any requests originated from a different service. Any direct get/post requests to the service are not getting traced. The configuration is the same as the one on the sample app below.
https://github.com/ThomasVitale/spring-boot-opentelemetry/tree/main/traces-otel
Any idea why the traces are not showing for all the REST calls and only for actuator health endpoint?
Thank you in advance!
SG

I am also struggling with the same problem.
